# Finding difference between consecutive numbers in an array

Tags: java

I need following output
Ex:

`int array [] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};`

Should be done using for loop

Output should be in form:

```
List      Difference
 1            0
 2            1
 3            1
 4            1
 5            1
```

Here's the code I'm using, it works fine till 4 but then at 5 it says outofbounds because its looking at position 5 in array which does not exits. So, I need help!!!

Code:

```
for (int counter = 0; counter < degreedays.length;++counter){
    System.out.println("\t" + degreedays[counter] + "\t\t\t" + (degreedays[counter+1] - degreedays[counter]));
```

Comment: If this is homework, please tag it as such. Also, this community is here to help you, not to do things for you. So please show us what you've done so far and what you're stuck/confused on.

Comment: fibunacci serries? seems like so. on second a modified version of it, probably seems like fibunacci

Comment: I got output working but when I run the loop, it gives me an error for value 5 it says outofbounds. Here's my code:

Comment: for (int counter = 0; counter < degreedays.length;++counter){
    System.out.println("\t" + degreedays[counter] + "\t\t\t" +                  (degreedays[counter+1] - degreedays[counter]));
            sum = sum + degreedays[counter];
        }

Comment: Consecutive numbers, doesn't that *inherently imply* that each number increases by 1? This is an assignment!?

Comment: @Vivek: since you indicated this is part of a project in response to it being homework, you should remove the homework tag. Unless you mean it's homework for a project?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your code loops through all indices of the array using a canonical for-loop, which is fine; however, the body of the loop uses not only the index (`counter`) but also the index plus one (`counter+1`), which is outside the range of the indices of the array!

Correct your code so that it doesn't try to access an array element which is out of bounds, e.g. by checking if "counter+1" is a valid index before trying to use it.

Answer (score 1):

The last iteration of your for loop is referencing one past the end of your array, so you get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. You need to deal with the first iteration as a special case since it's always zero. Then for the rest of the loop subtract the current index minus the last index. E.g.:

```
int[] degreedays = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
for (int counter = 0; counter < degreedays.length; ++counter) {
    int diff = counter == 0 ? 0 : degreedays[counter] - degreedays[counter - 1];
    System.out.println("\t" + degreedays[counter] + "\t\t\t" + diff);
}
```

Comment: i think that would work iff the difference between consecutive numbers is constant what if all the number were random. Then I set the difference for first element equals to zero but then the loop continues to subtract from next number but when we reach 5 same problem. Isn't it??

Answer (score 0):

These sorts of things can be done various ways. Here's how I'd do it:

```
int array [] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
int Previous = array[0]; // Keeps previous value of array and is used to print.
System.out.println("List   Difference");
for (int I=0; I<array.length(); I++) {
    int J=I+1;
    Previous = Previous - array[I];
    System.out.println(" "+J+"   "+Previous);
    Previous = array[I];
}
```

But be warned, your instructor may not appreciate my style of code as it dates me as having learned Fortran-66 as my first language.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
    int[] degreedays = new int[] { -81, -2, -3, 10, Integer.MIN_VALUE,1,Integer.MAX_VALUE };// works for random numbers too.
    if(degreedays != null && degreedays.length > 0) {
        System.out.println("\t" + degreedays[0] + "\t\t\t0");

        for (int counter = 1; counter < degreedays.length; ++counter) {
            long s = degreedays[counter];
            long f = degreedays[counter-1];
            System.out.println("\t" + degreedays[counter] + "\t\t\t" + Math.abs(s-f) ); 
        }
    }
```